# Virtal Assistant throwing 'Sorry it looks like something went wrong'

Tags: azure, botframework

I have created a virtual assistant using the Microsoft virtual assistant template. When testing in the emulator whatever message i send i am getting a 'something went wrong reply.'

I am new to the entire bot framework ecosystem and it is becoming very difficult to proceed.

In the log what i can see is:

```
    [11:26:32]Emulator listening on http://localhost:65233
[11:26:32]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
[11:26:32]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[11:26:32]Edit ngrok settings
[11:26:32]POST201directline.startConversation
[11:26:39]<-messageapplication/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive
[11:26:39]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:26:54]->messagehi
[11:26:55]<-traceThe given key 'en' was not present in the dictiona...
[11:26:55]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:26:55]<-trace at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_...
[11:26:55]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:26:55]<-messageSorry, it looks like something went wrong.
[11:26:55]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:26:55]POST200directline.postActivity
[11:27:48]->messagehello
[11:27:48]<-traceThe given key 'en' was not present in the dictiona...
[11:27:48]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:27:48]<-trace at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_...
[11:27:48]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:27:48]<-messageSorry, it looks like something went wrong.
[11:27:48]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
[11:27:48]POST200directline.postActivity
```

From what I understood the 'en' is not present in dictionary and I am not sure what is means. I checked in the Responses folder and could not see an en file not sure if that is the issue:

[image]

My emulator screenshot is attached:

[image]

Any help would be useful.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint inside the following block in the `DefaultAdapter` file `OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>` and when an exception is thrown your breakpoint will be hit and you can inspect the exception/stack trace as per [this image](https://i.imgur.com/b08q059.png). That said English is the default language for the template so it should work out of the box. You could try checking that the locale for the emulator (settings cog in the bottom left) is set to en-US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you are experiencing is a problem on the following lines inside `MainDialog.cs`:

```
var locale = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
var cognitiveModels = _services.CognitiveModelSets[locale];
```

This tries to use the locale (retrieved from the current thread as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8)) as the key to access the cognitive models in your `cognitivemodels.json` file.

Inside your `cognitivemodels.json` file it should look like:

```
{
  "cognitiveModels": {
    // This line below here is what could be missing/incorrect in yours
    "en": {
      "dispatchModel": {
        "type": "dispatch",
        "region": "westus",
        ...
      },
      "knowledgebases": [
        {
          "id": "chitchat",
          "name": "chitchat",
          ...
        },
        {
          "id": "faq",
          "name": "faq",
          ...
        },
      ],
      "languageModels": [
        {
          "id": "general",
          "name": "msag-test-va-boten_general",
          "region": "westus",
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "defaultLocale": "en-us"
}
```

The `en` key insides the `cognitiveModels` object is what the code is trying to use to retrieve your cognitive models, thus if the `locale` pulled out in the code doesn't match the locale keys in your `cognitivemodels.json` then you will get the dictionary key error.

**EDIT**

The issue the OP has was a failed deploy. The steps we took were to:

- Checked the `deploy_log.txt` inside the `Deployment` folder for errors.

  - If this case it was empty - not a good sign.
- Checked the `deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt` inside the `Deployment` folder for errors.

  - There was an error present `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dip_chatterjee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botdispatch\bin\dispatch.js`.

    - To fix this error we reinstalled all of the required npm packages as per step 5 of [this guide](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md#download-and-install) then ran the deploy script as per [this guide](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md#deploy-your-assistant).

Comment: I am using it from INDIA which should be locale but my bot is hosted as westus.. what should i do next then? I intend to use the bot in English only.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the "en" key in your `cognitivemodels.json` file? Hosting in the westus is fine because that is the only region that some of the cognitive services are available in.

Comment: {
  "cognitiveModels": {},
  "defaultLocale": "en-us"
}

Comment: Ok, there is your problem, your cognitiveModels section is empty. When you create a new project using the Virtual Assistant template it should look like [this](https://pastebin.com/wfMfD3E4). In order to fill this out you will need to deploy the necessary cognitive services as per step 1 and 2 of  [this guide](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md#deploy-your-assistant).

Comment: But that is how I did it, i followed the above guide only. in .\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1 location field i gave westus

Comment: Can you check in the Azure portal to see if any resources exist for your bot? If not you should run the deploy command again and screenshot the entire outcome (please cover up the app id you enter before posting). So that we can see that it ran with no errors. Because if that deploy script runs successfully it should populate your ‘cognitivemodels.json’ file via [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Deployment/Scripts/deploy.ps1#L197) which calls ‘deploy_cognitive_models.ps1’.

Comment: On the [final line](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Deployment/Scripts/deploy_cognitive_models.ps1#L190) of the ‘deploy_cognitive_models.ps1’ script it updates your ‘cognitivemodels.json’ file via this command ‘$settings | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | OutFile $(Join-Path $outputFolder “cognitivemodels.json”)’. As stated above  please run the ‘deploy.ps1’ script again and post the outcome via pastebin or a similar service.

Comment: The resources are there in my azure portal [link](https://pasteboard.co/IhlguxH.png). Should I still redeploy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194276/discussion-between-dip-ranjan-chatterjee-and-matt-stannett).